# InstallShield LaunchAppAndWait nltest

Tags: command-line, installshield

I need to find out domain controller name of domain user inputs during installation.
in command line I can use command "nltest /dcname:"

when trying to use this in installshield script I run into all sorts of problems.

fist I tried this:

`strCmdLine = "/C \"nltest /dcname:" + strDomain + " \" > output.txt";`
`LaunchAppAndWait("cmd.exe", strCmdLine, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT | LAAW_OPTION_SHOW_HOURGLASS | LAAW_OPTION_HIDDEN);`

output.txt file is created but its empty.

I also tried to use `LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas";`

next I tried this:

`strCmdLine = "/C \"c:\\Windows\\System32\\nltest.exe /dcname:" + strDomain + "\"";`
`LaunchApplication("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", strCmdLine, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\", SW_NORMAL, INFINITE, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT | LAAW_OPTION_USE_SHELLEXECUTE)`

I get error `'c:\Windows\System32\nltest.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`, no idea why.

I tried all combinations of different LaunchApp commands, escape symbols and quotes with no success... any idea how to successfully store output of nltest??

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be done during installation, or could you do this after installation on application launch?

---

***Win32***: Doing a quick dependency scan on that EXE reveals a number of Win32 functions and managed APIs that can be used instead implemented in **`NTDSAPI.dll`** and **`LOGONCLI.DLL`**.

Some documentation can be found here:

- [DsGetDomainControllerInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ntdsapi/nf-ntdsapi-dsgetdomaincontrollerinfoa) (pinvoke.net: [DsGetDomainControllerInfo](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdsapi.DsGetDomainControllerInfo))
- [DsEnumerateDomainTrusts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Dsgetdc/nf-dsgetdc-dsenumeratedomaintrustsa) (pinvoke.net: [DsEnumerateDomainTrusts](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/DsEnumerateDomainTrusts.html))

More functions:

- [Domain Controller and Replication Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/AD/dc-and-replication-management-functions)
- [Directory Service Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/AD/directory-service-functions)

---

***Alternative Managed API***: **`System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory`**.

---

Calling these Win32 functions should be relatively easy from a C++ dll or Installscript.

***Quick Suggestion***: Rather than spending much time with a C-style API (which can take hours), I like to pillage github.com for [a quick sample that can be adapted](https://github.com/smuehlst/circle-newlib/blob/8a313d45ad5d8c0e306ce8751b6e3d6d3ef46ab3/winsup/cygwin/uinfo.cc). That was just the first thing I saw that made any sense at all. There should be much better if you look.

Answer (score 0):

While the suggestion to look for an API instead of an EXE is good, that doesn't answer your question. I'll start with part 2: why can't it find nltest.exe?

Likely because, at least if it's like my 64-bit system here, nltest.exe resides only in the (64-bit) System32 folder. It does not reside in the (32-bit) SysWOW64 folder. Since the InstallScript engine is a 32-bit process, all attempts to refer to C:\Windows\System32 are redirected to C:\Windows\SysWOW64. You can test this theory at the command line by launching C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe (the 32-bit command prompt) and typing in your commands there.

You can work around this one of two ways: [Disable](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefDisable00000677.htm)/[Enable](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefEnable00000679.htm)(WOW64FSREDIRECTION) allowing [WINSYSDIR64](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefWINSYSDIR64.htm) to mean the right thing, or substitute [Sysnative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) for System32 in your hardcoded path. Note that the latter must only be used on a 64-bit operating system by a 32-bit process, as otherwise Sysnative is just a missing folder. By contrast, the Disable/Enable(WOW64FSREDIRECTION) call should do nothing on a 32-bit system.

Back to part 1, why did it create an empty output.txt file? Just the magic of how the cmd's process invocations with redirections work. First it creates the file and hooks it to the output of the process it's about to create. Then (per above) it fails to launch the process, so nothing is added. Finally, since only stdout was redirected and the windows were hidden, there was no way to inform you of the error.